# sending DateTime to WCF service serialized as default

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, serialization

so i have the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Client
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int MerchantID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastPing { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SessionToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.Guid GUID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime cDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }

}
```

i use it on my WCF like this:
(interface)

```
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Client))]
    void CreateClient(Client inClient);
```

and the WCF implementation:

```
    public void CreateClient(Client inClient)
    {
        try
        {
            CMSUsersManager manager = new CMSUsersManager();
            manager.CreateClient(inClient);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

i have another project (kind of website) which i am invoking that service:

```
        CPanelService.CPanelService service;
        service = new CPanelService.CPanelService();
        service.CreateClient(inClient);
```

Now  for my problem:
"inClient" on the website contains `inClient.cDate = DateTime.Now`.
when the request is sent to the WCF the service receives `inClient.cDate = 1/1/001 00:00:00`

i tried to figure out, no luck.

can somebody please enlighten me?
thanks.

Comment: can I see the `inClient` object that you're creating?

Comment: the `cDate` isn't nullable, so it's being assigned the `default` value instead of `null `.

Comment: The inClient.cDate is initialized with DateTime.Now. using debugger i can see that it is set and it is sent to the service "valued" (and not null). the service however recieves minVal or something, though it should contain a value

Comment: strange .. isn't it?

Comment: var newClient = new Client
        {
            AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo,
            Address = address,
            cDate = DateTime.Now,
            ClientName = username,
            Email = email,
            LastSeen = null,
            MerchantID = currUser.MerchantID,
            Name = name,
            Password = password,
            SessionToken = null
        };

Answer (score 0):

In order to send properties across the wire, you have to explicitly input the Data Annotation `[DataMember]` above their headers:

```
[DataMember]
public string Email { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string Address { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public System.DateTime cDate { get; set; }
```

Do it for all your properties.

And on the class header you also put `[DataContract]`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Client
```

I am not sure that this will solve your problem, but I can guarantee you'll have eventual headaches with serialization (which seems to be your current one) if you don't add those annotations.

Comment: OP's got problem with `cDate` only.

Comment: I had problems before with only a few properties. Adding `DataMember` annotation solved it for me. Having it on all properties is just to maintain good practice.

Comment: strange that `types` you use in `WCF` aren't `DataContacts`.

Comment: The Client is in class library in a self project. i dont seem to be able to add it [DataMember].

Comment: add reference to `System.ServiceModel` & let me know if that works.

Comment: Same problem.. it didnt fixed it.

Comment: Can you update your question with the data annotations?

Comment: `WCF` by default uses `DataContractSerialization` from long back

Comment: Well, i have find out what the problem was.
there is something i am struggling with for few days now, it's something called "Specified". when i send an int ID for example i need to fill another parameter call "IDSpecified" (with true or false). because that was a class there was an additional field inside called "cDateSpecified". once set it to "true" it worked.

is there a way to remove that "specified" thing?